# Any good converter for GB, Big5, Unicode

Tags: unicode, cjk

Any good converter for GB, Big5, Unicode?

Convert GB to Unicode, Unicode to GB, Big5 to Unicode, Unicode to Big5, GB to Big5.

Comment: Short answer: Yes

Longer answer: As to which those are will depend on your language of choice. What are your language / platform / price / license requirements? Do you need a library or is a standalone app preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iconv should be able to do the job.  It's part of the GNU C Library.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv
http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommand to use from **Unicode Converter** provided by codeplex at http://unicode.codeplex.com it is free and open source software with GNU 2.0 License.

this application convert a char or a sring to Hxcde or Decimal and gives you a complete information about each char, you can create a unicode text by provided editor and change your sentense at any time,

really a good and usefull app

Answer (score 0):

If it's a converting tool that you need, you can try:

```
http://alf-li.pcdiscuss.com/c_convertz.html
```

Really useful to me, it does GB/BIG5/UNICODE.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), the International Components for Unicode. Most likely you will find what you need there.

Answer (score 0):

iconv can handle these.

- Convert GB to Unicode
- Unicode to GB
- Big5 to Unicode
- Unicode to Big5

But not

- GB to Big5.

It is expected many missing characters.